# How to run a method on all elements in a list c# to improve load times

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asynchronous

I have a project in work that requires fetching data for over 300 users via a REST API and the user can't proceed with using the app properly until all of this data is fetched. Ideally, I would like to run the FetchUserDetails method on each element in the list at the same time and update each entry as the details return.

Note: To prevent blocking the UI thread, this functionality is nested in a background worker.

My User class looks something like :

```
public class User 
{
    public List<string> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the background worker, I have the following functionality:

```
List<User> users; // List of 300+ users
Parallel.ForEach(users, user =>
{
    user.Details = FetchUserDetails(user);
});
```

And the FetchUserDetails method, without going into specifics due to NDA restrictions:

```
private List<string> FetchUserDetails(User inputUser)
{
    // Long running, nested API calls that take over 50 seconds
    return List<string>;
}
```

Is there a way for me to run the method on each of the 300+ entries simultaneously to drastically reduce the time it takes for the data to be fetched.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the call to `FetchUserDetails` takes more than 50 seconds for a single user?

Comment: @meJustAndrew no, apologies for the lack of clarity. In total, the requests will take approx 50 secs to complete for all users.

Comment: Is it taking 50 seconds to compute those details, or 50 seconds to go off to databases/web-services/other-IO-centric-places?  Your Parallel.ForEach method will dispatch each fetch to a thread pool thread.  In order not to overwhelm things by dispatching work to count-of-users threads, it will start using N threads (where N is, I believe, the number of procs on the box), and then dispatch more work each time a unit of work completes.  Consider making your FetchUserDetails async, and do those NDA API calls asynchronously, if possible.

Comment: I understood it was 50 seconds/user too.  In any case, my points stay the same  You might want to update that comment in the code in your post

Comment: Okay, that's better! So, is this data that you are fetching, something that changes a lot or not? In the end, my goal would be to cache it and only refresh it from time to time, eventually based on some rules.

Comment: Start with the BlockingCollection<T>. First, shove all the requests into the queue. Second create a single reader thread that pulls off items and hands them off to threads in a worker pool. Third, have the workers shove the answers into another queue. When the reader detects that the queue is empty then let it join the other threads. Once they're all joined send message back to your main thread. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Parallel.ForEach does allow you to set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    users, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 300 },
    user => { user.Details = FetchUserDetails(user); }
);
```

You can even do -1 for MaxDegreeOfParallelism to mean unlimited

However setting this will actually only reduce the number it will use. See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_MaxDegreeOfParallelism) for details.

> By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

As others have pointed out the number of threads actually used is likely to be limited to the number of cores your machine has.

A better approach would be to make the calls async, so that once a request is blocked waiting for a response the original thread is free to start the next request.

Something like:

```
async Task SetUserDetails(User user)
{
    user.Details = await FetchUserDetails(user);
}

async Task UpdateUsers(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
         tasks.Add(SetUserDetails(user));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: If your machine has only 8 cores, then 8 threads will be all that it will be able to process at a given time. Splitting the work on more threads will not help much. I believe that he has a bottleneck somewhere else in the code, but he has to figure out or give us more details...

Comment: Yes I agree but now he has the info about what Parallel.ForEach does

Comment: You're absolutely correct that your second (async task-based) approach is better... he'll have way fewer blocked threads lying around if he goes async. Parallel.ForEach is intended for CPU-bound workloads, not I/O intensive work.

Comment: Note to OP the 300 is misleading, all this will do is use up all the available threadpool threads on IO work and *bottleneck*. because this is `async`, its probably best use `WhenAll`, you will get a bigger performance boost